# Javascript function runs both routes

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronization

Still have problems with this. When I call this function it appears to return twice??? I get 'test2' in the console followed by 'test'. I also put the callback return value into the console and its false then true. The getwidget is only called once from this.nextwidget which is a button.

```
      getwidget = function (callback) {
          var id = get_name_value('salesperson');
          var password = 'password';
          if (id !== "") {
              $.get('http://somewhere.com?id=' + id + '&password=' + password,
                  function (data, status) {
                      console.log(status);
                      if (status === 'success') {
                        catalogue = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if (catalogue.status === "error") {
                            alert(catalogue.message);
                        } else {
                            console.log('test');
                            if (callback) callback(true);
                        }
                      } else {
                        alert("Error connecting to API:" + status);
                      }
                  });
          }
          console.log('test2');
          if (callback) callback(false);
      };

      this.nextwidget = function() {
          catindex = catindex + 1;

          getwidget(function(trigger) {
            if (!trigger && catindex > 0) {
                catindex = catindex - 1;
            }
            if (catindex === catlen - 1) {
                document.getElementById("nextwidget").disabled = true;
            }
            if (catindex !== 0) {
                document.getElementById("prevwidget").disabled = false;
            }
            console.log(catindex);
            console.log(trigger);
          });
      };
```

Comment: test2 is logging to the console followed by test because of the delay waiting for call to `$.get` to finish...

Comment: you might want to also clarify what the problem is here.. what are you wanting or expecting to happen?

Comment: It looks like you're calling your callback twice: after you send the request you run `if (callback) callback(false);` (before the response might I add), then later in the callback of your request you call the original callback again with `if (callback) callback(true);`

Comment: OK - so what I'm wanting to happen is call the getwidget, this fills the catalogue array and then returns to the nextwidget function.

Comment: It looks like you might want to wrap the part after the `if (id !== "")` block into `else { ... }`? The behavior you describe is exactly what I expect when I look at that code.

Comment: So if I only use the call back once it will only return back once ?

Comment: Did you read @PatrickBarr's comment? It explains the exact sequence of events. To be clear: 1. calling the callback doesn't exit the function 2. even disregarding that you don't seem to understand that `$.get` is _async_, you are calling the `callback` twice deliberately in your code.

Comment: Brilliant - I know understand! I was doing a return as such from other languages (not done loads of javascript like this). So I was trying to make sure all paths had a return but in a callback it seems that I shouldn't do that. Makes sense now, lost so many hours on this! Thx

Comment: I'm glad you solved this, but not sure where you're getting "I was trying to make sure all paths had a return" from? Your code doesn't contain a single `return`...

Comment: No sorry - I meant in other languages I use returns in my functions to cover the paths and that was what I was doing here. Why do I need to say if (callback) callback(false);? Can I just say callback(false);?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is asynchronous. 
*$.get* operation is asynchronous, because it is a call to the server.

It means that JS is not waiting till the end of this operation and just continuing excuting next block of code. 
So, according to your code, it shows 'test2' in a console, than executes callback with **false** parameter. And only when response from server received, it shows "test" in console and run callback with **true** parameter. 
(certainly, if request was successful, according to your snippet)

Here is simple jsfiddle for better understanding how it works.
[Simple async example](https://jsfiddle.net/cd1e2w3b/)

```
function asyncExample() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('test');
  }, 1000);

  console.log('test2')
}

asyncExample();
```

Because operation in **timeout** is delayed (like asynchronous), JS will not wait and just continue with next lines. So the result will be:
'test2' first and then 'test'.